# Update latlng object fields in leafletJS

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm quite new to leaflet, so excuse me if this may sound trivial, but let's say i have 2 latlng objects and i want to update their lat,lng field how should i proceed?

I tought something like this would work, but apparently doesn't.

```
sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();

                    if (sw.lat < -90 ){sw.lat = -90;  }
                    if (sw.lng < -180){sw.lon = -180; }
                    if (ne.lng >  90 ){ne.lat =  90;  }
                    if (ne.lng >  180){ne.lon =  180; }
```

can someone tell me what's the correct way to proceed ?

Comment: You're trying to set the boundary of the map? Or you're trying to set your objects?

Comment: i'm trying to set my objects, the problem is that even with wraps and repetition disabled when i print the bb of the map the values are greater than [-180,-90]  and [180,90] so when this happens i want to alert pass the normalized value to the db

Comment: as an example at zoom-lvl 0 my bb[southwest,northeast] is: [-843.75, -89.92732325125809], [843.75, 89.9273232512581]

Answer (score 1):

the simple answer is that that's the correct way, but it's not sw.lon nor ne.lon... is in fact .lng !!! beware of the infamous notation guys!

Comment: BTW, the [documentation for `L.LatLng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#latlng-property) is quite clear on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Take the values using wrap:

```
sw = map.bounds.getSouthWest().wrap()
```

And set the maxBounds

```
map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(sw, ne));
```

Comment: i found it, strange enough on zoom 0 with all the map displayed one would expect the bounds to be -180,-90 180,90... and insted is not like that: -123.75,-89.92732325125809,123.75,89.9273232512581

Comment: wrap give you the bound of the full image

Comment: you need get the values of your view and set maxbounds according of your view